# Karatsuba C++ implementation

Tags: c++, optimization, algorithm

I've written an algorithm for integer multiplication using the Karatsuba method in C++. This implementation is far from ideal, so any comments are welcome.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>

#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>

const int MAX_LENGTH = 50000 * 2 + 1;

void add_leading_zeros(char* a, int n) {
  int lena = strlen(a);
  for (int i = lena - 1 + n; i >= n; --i) {
    a[i] = a[i - n];
  }
  a[lena + n] = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    a[i] = '0';
  }
}

void remove_leading_zeros(char* a) {
  int lena = strlen(a);
  int ind = 0;
  while (ind < lena && a[ind] == '0') {
    ++ind;
  }

  for (int i = ind; i < lena; ++i) {
    a[i - ind] = a[i];
  }
  a[lena - ind] = 0;
}

void sum(char* a, char* b, char* res) {
  int lena = strlen(a);
  int lenb = strlen(b);

  if (lena < lenb) {
    std::swap(a, b);
    std::swap(lena, lenb);
  }

  int toAdd = 0;
  for (int inda = lena - 1, indb = lenb - 1; inda >= 0; --inda, --indb) {
    int x = a[inda] - '0';
    int y = indb >= 0 ? b[indb] - '0' : 0;

    int cur = x + y + toAdd;

    if (cur >= 10) {
      toAdd = 1;
      cur -= 10;
    } else {
      toAdd = 0;
    }

    res[inda] = cur + '0';
  }

  if (toAdd == 1) {
    add_leading_zeros(res, 1);
    res[0] = '1';
  }
}

// assume that a > b
void sub(char* a, char* b, char* res) {
  int lena = strlen(a);
  int lenb = strlen(b);

  //assert(lena >= lenb);

  int toSub = 0;
  for (int inda = lena - 1, indb = lenb - 1; inda >= 0; --inda, --indb) {
    int x = a[inda] - '0';
    int y = indb >= 0 ? b[indb] - '0' : 0;

    if (toSub == 1) {
      x--;
    }
    int cur;
    if (x < y) {
      cur = x + 10 - y;
      toSub = 1;
    } else {
      cur = x - y;
      toSub = 0;
    }

    res[inda] = cur + '0';
  }
}

// returns a * 10^n
void mult10(char* a, int n) {
  int lena = strlen(a);

  if (lena == 1 && a[0] == '0') {
    return;
  }

  for (int i = lena; i < lena + n; ++i) {
    a[i] = '0';
  }
  a[lena + n] = 0;
}

char* CreateArray(int len) {
  char* res = new char[len];
  memset(res, 0, len);
  return res;
}

// add leading zeros if needed
void make_equal_length(char* a, char* b) {
  int lena = strlen(a);
  int lenb = strlen(b);

  int n = std::max(lena, lenb);

  add_leading_zeros(a, n - lena);
  add_leading_zeros(b, n - lenb);
}

void karatsuba(char* x, char* y, char* res) {
  make_equal_length(x, y);

  int len = strlen(x);
  if (len == 1) {
    int val = (x[0] - '0') * (y[0] - '0');
    if (val < 10) {
      res[0] = val + '0';
    } else {
      res[0] = (val / 10) + '0';
      res[1] = (val % 10) + '0';
    }
  } else {
    char* xl = CreateArray(len);
    char* xr = CreateArray(len);
    char* yl = CreateArray(len);
    char* yr = CreateArray(len);

    int rightSize = len / 2;
    int leftSize = len - rightSize;

    strncpy(xl, x, leftSize);
    strcpy(xr, x + leftSize);
    strncpy(yl, y, leftSize);
    strcpy(yr, y + leftSize);

    int maxl = 3 * len;
    char* P1 = CreateArray(maxl);
    char* P2 = CreateArray(maxl);
    char* P3 = CreateArray(maxl);

    karatsuba(xl, yl, P1);
    karatsuba(xr, yr, P2);

    char* tmp1 = CreateArray(maxl);
    char* tmp2 = CreateArray(maxl);

    sum(xl, xr, tmp1);
    sum(yl, yr, tmp2);
    karatsuba(tmp1, tmp2, P3);

    sub(P3, P1, P3);
    sub(P3, P2, P3);
    mult10(P3, rightSize);

    mult10(P1, 2 * rightSize);

    sum(P1, P2, res);
    sum(res, P3, res);

    remove_leading_zeros(res);

    delete[] xl;
    delete[] xr;
    delete[] yl;
    delete[] yr;
    delete[] tmp1;
    delete[] tmp2;
    delete[] P1;
    delete[] P2;
    delete[] P3;
  }
}

int main() {
  char a[MAX_LENGTH], b[MAX_LENGTH];
  scanf("%s\n%s", a, b);

  char* res = CreateArray(MAX_LENGTH);
  karatsuba(a, b, res);

  printf("%s\n", res);

  scanf("%d", 1);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This mostly looks like C, especially with all this dynamic memory allocation.  Is this intentional?

Comment: @Jamal, yes, because I prefer using C strings.

Comment: @pfedotovsky, you can check this one http://habrahabr.ru/post/124258/ code goes below description

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm

Comment: Why are you doing biginteger arithmetic in base10 instead of binary?

Comment: Please use `std::vector`.

Comment: Please use std::string. Weather you prefer them or not is irelavant. They are notoriously the place for bugs and are super inefficient in terms of memory management when compared to std::string.

Comment: This is not C++ it is just C code that is compiled by the C++ compiler (and happens to use new/delete rather than malloc/free (which makes it even worse as the C-String libraries are not aware of this and half the C-String libraries for string manipulation do memory management thus making this code unmaintainable as anybody modifying the code has to know this and make sure they don't use a specific sub set of the string manipulation library.

Answer (score 12):

If you prefer programming in C-style, I suggest to use C.
If you want to use any part of C++, I suggest to embrace it fully.

I'll review only the `main` method for now,
I'm sure a lot more reviews will come from others.

---

You don't need the `\n` here. You can just drop it, it will work the same way:

> ```
>   scanf("%s\n%s", a, b);
> ```

The C++ equivalent:

```
std::cin >> a >> b;
```

---

This generates a compiler warning, for good reason:
the arguments of `scanf` should be pointers, but it's an `int`.
Why is this line there at all? I suggest to remove it.

> ```
>   scanf("%d", 1);
> ```

Comment: *"If you want to use any part of C++, I suggest to embrace it fully."* ... +1 ... I always ask the C heads to consider the points made in [Learning Standard C++ as a New Language](http://www.stroustrup.com/new_learning.pdf) for starters.

Answer (score 8):

Some random observations:

- `toAdd` and `toSub` are traditionally called `carry`. Consider renaming.
- `sub` assumes that `a > b`. Does this assumption hold? In general, I don't see any provision to deal with negative numbers.
- Keeping digits as ascii, and converting them back and forth at each operation seems wasteful, both time and space wise.
- By using C-style arrays you are forced to track the length separately. I strongly recommend to switch to `std::vector`.
- `sum` would fail when adding strings of the same length (`inda` becomes -1 after the loop termination). In general I don't think the decision to keep most significant digit at the index 0 is justified.
- `sum` apparently doesn't let its parameters to be aliased (you can't `sum(x, y, x)`), which leads to many unnecessary allocations.

Answer (score 6):

Separate your `#include`s by type and order them alphabetically if possible.
E.g.: Put all the C library headers together and all the C++ headers together (the C library ones are those starting with a `c`: `<cstdlib>`, `<cstdio>`, etc).

---

Your naming convention is not fully consistent. Most of the code uses `snake_case`, but you have some `camelCase` as well:

```
int toSub;
CreateArray();
```

You should be fully consistent with your choice:

```
int to_sub;
create_array();
```

---

You don't have to `return 0` from `main()`. The compiler will add that for you if you don't explicitly do so.

---

Currently, your code uses very few C++ features. I would suggest moving completely to plain C (basically just replacing `new/delete` with `malloc/free`).

Answer (score 6):

One problem with combining C and C++ is that others may not know for sure if you're really trying to combine both for whatever reason, or if you think they're the same (some aren't aware that they're two separate languages).  The use of `delete` signifies C++, but then you have several lines of `delete`s in one of the functions, which is not good practice in C++ as you have the standard library that manages the memory for you.  You could fail to deallocate something yourself, causing a memory leak.

Actually, it already happens with `res` that gets allocated in `CreateArray()`.  Who is responsible for its deletion now?  Certainly not `CreateArray()`, as it returns the array and leaves scope.  You should just allocate the arrays within the calling function and then deallocate from there.  Yes, this is a concern when you have to manage your own memory in non-garbage-collected languages like C and C++.

It's also hard to tell what `karatsuba()` is doing algorithmic-wise.  It lacks commenting and appears to do a lot of memory management.  If you cannot improve it in C, then you may have to do it *only* in C++ while utilizing the standard library.

Comment: the `char *x = CreateArray(n);` lines can be replaced by `vector<char> x(n);` at practically no cost. It's easy to transition step-by-step since `x.data()` returns a `char *` pointer the C-style code can use.